# Circle/Blob detection basics

Tags: image-processing, aforge, object-detection

I need to be able to detect spots on sample tiles.  The spots themselves are applied to the sample tiles by hand and as such are not particularly regular in shape or position.

[image: Tiles with spots]

I've been playing around with [Aforge.NET](http://code.google.com/p/aforge/)'s blob detection and have had some limited success using the [ChannelFiltering](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/e053df99-306d-1bbe-52ec-44f327fe789b.htm) and [ColorFiltering](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/35bd90e3-4e35-8f5f-e255-26c5d8d4b927.htm) filters.  However, to do this I need to manually define a range of RGB values that match the spot colors on the example image.  This simply won't work in the Real World, where factors such as lighting conditions and problems with the fabrication of the sample tiles will come into effect.

I'm guessing I should initially convert the image to grayscale and then apply a series of filters or other operations before I run the blob detection algorithm, but I'm at a loss as to what these should be.

Are there some best practices for circle/blob detection?

EDIT: fixed links.

Comment: Any chance of investing in a decent camera? Your image quality is awful.

Comment: Perhaps I should have mentioned: the image above is actually a photo of a printout.  I have not yet been provided with the tiles themselves, only a digital image.  So, the image you are seeing is actually that of a piece of paper.  I am confident the camera we're using is good enough for the intended purpose.